# How to retrieve a html file content and insert to another html file?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to write templates for a mobile app, as I only know pure JavaScript, so my plan is replacing the default template with a new one. After few hours I was nearly exhausted on this issue. It is not CORS thing and all the files are in localhost.

```
function getTheme(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "model/1/index.html", true);
    xhr.responseType = "document";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 0) {
                var customTheme = document.getElementById('crapDiv');
                customTheme.innerHTML = xhr.responseXML;
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

This Ajax works quite fine when I test with a text file, but as MDN said, to retrieve a html with ajax, a "document" responseType must be declared, thus, with the xhr.responseXML it only returns a DOM object, which is [object HTMLDocument]

I just can not parse this object back into contents so that I could not insert it into another html file.

So, How could I get through with this issue plz? and, plz only pure JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it.

```
function getTheme(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "model/1/index.html", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 0) {
                var customTheme = document.getElementById('crapDiv');
                customTheme.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

The diff is just the declare of the responseType, by default it is "", and xhr.responseText is the right way to retrieve the content, while the xhr.responseXML is the right way to retrieve the DOM object.

As it should be xhr.responseText, so there is no more need to declare responseType, and must be "" or "Text" if you still want a decalration.

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit a file's content with JavaScripts, you can only read it. It's not for that. You need a server with eg PHP that can save your data.

You can get the response data as raw text with `xhr.responseText`.

Comment: no, I am not saying to modify the file forever, I just want to make it interactive, the FE stuff. If I could do this, than I could also send the final modification to apache I suppose, but my boss want me to do it, I am not quite sure this is the front-end job :)